# Add custom action in post type

Tags: metabox, actions

I use the http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/meta-box Metabox plugin and I want to add a custom action in a post type like the publish button ? when admin click on this button I want to send an email to the author and delete the current post type.

I have added the button in my post like this :

```
    // meta box
    $meta_boxes[] = array(
            'title' => __('Reviewer','sparta'),
            'pages' => array( 'download'),
            'fields' => array(
                array(
            'name' => __('Reject','sparta'),
            'desc' => __('reject this                  post.','sparta'),
                      'id' => $prefix . 'reject_post',
                      'type' => 'button',
                      'std' => ''
                )));
```

My question is how to execute my action from this button ?
someone has an idea ?

Thank you very much

Comment: What happens when you click the button? Does the form submit? Are you hoping to do this via AJAX? Please clarify.

Comment: when i hit the button no things happen, here the code for the button field : https://github.com/rilwis/meta-box/blob/master/inc/fields/button.php

Comment: Is the generated markup for the button correct?

Comment: yes it is :<div class="rwmb-input"><a href="#" id="wp_author_reject" class="button hide-if-no-js">Click me</a></div>

Comment: That "button" isn't really a button. It is a link and it looks like it is intended to operate via Javascript.

Answer (score -1):

I found this solution here:
WP plugin that add a button to post edit page that allow sending a notify to a contributor whose a post was not approved. It's possible customize the message including the reason for rejected approval.

https://github.com/Giuseppe-Mazzapica/GMRejectNotify

I have not tested it but it seems legit!